# Can Meiosis 2 be called as mitosis?

Tags: gamete

I know Meoisis involves a reductional division and an equational division.Say if I am asked a question to find the no. of divisions an egg mother cell undergoes in a Polygonum type division to form the 7 celled 8 nucleate stage, would the Meoisis2 be counted as a mitosis?
Then would it be said to have undergone 1 reduction division and 2 equational division(1Meoisis +2Mitosis).
Or is it just 1Meoisis +1Mitosis ?

Answer (score 1):

Meiosis 2 can not be called mitosis.

You correctly recognized there are similarities between Meiosis 2 and mitosis. In other contexts, however, there are further differences. For instance Mitosis usually does not recombine genetic material (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meiosis), and the molecules that regulate Meiosis 2 and Mitosis are different. Calling "Meiosis 2" "mitosis" could lead to miscommunication.

Comment: But  there aint any recombination in meoisis 2.And are the enzymes mediating Meoisis 2 different from Mitosis even if both are equational divisions?

Comment: In mitosis (usually) no crossovers have to be resolved - which contrasts meiosis 2; The results of mitosis and meiosis 2 are also different in terms of chromosome copy number; mitosis entry is regulated by the cell-cycle machinery whereas meiosis 2 is not. The resulting cells have distinct biological functions too - for instance in meiosis 2 the resulting cells will be gametes